# LVM reduce from one Logical volume and add it to another

Tags: lvm

i am having two volume groups vg1 and vg2

on vg1 i am having two Logical volumes LV1 and LV2 ,LV1 is full and LV2 is having more than 60% free space.

Is it possible to reduce Lv2 and then using that space to extend LV1

There is no free space left on Vg1.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to shrink the filesystem on LV2 first, then reduce the LV size then give it to LV1 and then expand that filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the logical volumes as boxes, and the filesystems as content inside those boxes. You need to shrink the content before you can shrink the box.

First shrink the filesystem on LV2 to a decent size, then shrink LV2. You should now have available space on the Volume Group to expand LV1 followed by an expansion of the the filesytem on LV2.